# With Activemq how can make more than one exclusive consumer for queue?

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, consumer

As you know we can use Exclusive Consumer which allows only a single consumer to consume from the queue at once to preseve order...but :
I have 4 consumer that I need all of them receive messages and preseve order for all of them but unfortunately we can use Exclusive consumer just for one consumer..what should I do?
Note : I don't want use topic
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want four consumers to read from a Queue then you don't want to use Exclusive consumer because as the name might imply it allows only a single "Exclusive" consumer to read from the Queue at a time.

If you don't use exclusive consumer then all four will read from the queue in round robin fashion essentially sharing the work of processing messages from the Queue.

If you want all of the to read the same messages then you either want to use Topics, or you might look at [ActiveMQ Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very good...another question is that can I use GroupID? I remind that I want to use queue not topic and I want all 4 consumer receive Message and after that message will be clean form queue

Comment: That's a new question that should be asked separately after you've tried it and have gained enough knowledge about it.